# How to get combinations of elements from a list?

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list `L = [1,2,3]`. What's the best way to get all the possible unique combinations of 2 elements from the list and output should get in iterative way like:

1st iter = `1 2`, 2nd iter = `1 3` and 3rd iter = `2 3`

Answer (score 6):

*The best way* is to use the [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), like this

```
from itertools import combinations
print [item for item in combinations(L, r = 2)]
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

You can iterate over that like this

```
for item in combinations(L, r = 2):
    print item
# (1, 2)
# (1, 3)
# (2, 3)
```

Or you can access the individual elements like this

```
for item in combinations(L, r = 2):
    print item[0], item[1]
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to split that combination again like (1, 2) i want to get 1 and 2 separately. Is there any shortest method?

Comment: @user3064366 Can you please explain with an example? You want the output like `[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]`?

Comment: After getting the each combination i want to split that combination again like: first i am getting output (1,2) and again 1 and 2 separately.

Comment: @user3064366 Please check the updated answer. Is that what you are looking for?