# multiplying and combining all elements in a list by all others but without duplication/repetition

Tags: python

```
we = [1,2,3,4]
for i in we:
    for e in we:
        print('('+str(i)+' - '+str(e)+')')
    #del we[0]
```

This is the result:

```
(1 - 1)
(1 - 2)
(1 - 3)
(1 - 4)
(2 - 1)
(2 - 2)
(2 - 3)
(2 - 4)
(3 - 1)
(3 - 2)
(3 - 3)
(3 - 4)
(4 - 1)
(4 - 2)
(4 - 3)
(4 - 4)
```

But I do not want the same elements to repeat like I have `(1 - 3)` so I do not want `(3 - 1)` to show and so on.
I also need to use for loops in this

Comment: How about `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` or just `itertools.combinations`, depending on whether you want pairs like (1-1) or not?

Comment: `for c in itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], 2): print(c)` # (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4) (3, 4)

Comment: @Darkonaut that's what I am looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: Are you sure you don't need (1-1) in it?

Comment: Ohh wait, Yes I do want (1-1)

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks I used itertools.combinations_with_replacement and I got it. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single line using `list comprehension` and `itertools.combinations`.

```py
from itertools import combinations
['({} - {})'.format(e[0], e[1]) for e in list(combinations([1,2,3, 4], 2))]
```

**Output**:

```
['(1 - 2)', '(1 - 3)', '(1 - 4)', '(2 - 3)', '(2 - 4)', '(3 - 4)']
```

#### References:

1. [Python - how to find all combinations of two numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754724/python-how-to-find-all-combinations-of-two-numbers-in-a-list)
2. [How to get combination of element from a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199099/how-to-get-combination-of-element-from-a-python-list)

Comment: I see that @Darknaut also suggested this method. So, voted up his comment.